# Running order change in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

I'm trying this code, but when I test in my browser (New Chrome) the move_1_3 function happens first, and then the move_1_2, could you please help how to correct it?
(in the code I want to change the position of 3 pictures)

```
window.onload = main;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function main(){
    backGround.src = "http://www.ednetti.hu/images/cj0n9l0o6m.jpg";
    backGround.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
        ballImg.src = "http://www.clipartsfree.net/vector/large/SABROG_Glass_Blue_Ball_Vector_Clipart.png";
        ballImg.onload = function (){
            cupImg.src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/m/s/0/t/K/blue-cup-hi.png";
            cupImg.onload = function(){
                timer = setInterval(move_1_2, timeStep);
                timer = setInterval(move_1_3, timeStep);
                //time3 = setInterval(move_2_3, timeStep);

            };
        };
    };
}

    function move_1_2 () {
    if (steps >2){
        return;
    }

    posX =((posX2-posX1)/density)*i;
    bposX =(bposX2-bposX1)/density*i;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    if(ballPos == 1){
        context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX1 + bposX, bposY, ballw, ballh);
    }
    else if(ballPos == 2){
        context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX2 - bposX, bposY, ballw, ballh);
    }
    else if(ballPos == 3){
        context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX3, bposY, ballw, ballh);
    }
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX1 + posX, posY, cupw, cuph);
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX3, posY, cupw, cuph);
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX2 - posX, posY, cupw, cuph);

    i++;
    if (i == density){
        i = 0;
        steps ++;
      switch (ballPos){
        case 1:
          ballPos = 2;
          break;

        case 2:
          ballPos = 1;
          break;

      }
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
function move_1_3 () {
if (steps >2){
    return;
}

posX =((posX3-posX1)/density)*i;
bposX =(bposX3-bposX1)/density*i;
context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
if(ballPos == 1){
    context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX1 + bposX, bposY, ballw, ballh);
}
else if(ballPos == 3){
    context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX3 - bposX, bposY, ballw, ballh);
}
else if(ballPos == 2){
    context.drawImage(ballImg, bposX2, bposY, ballw, ballh);
}
context.drawImage(cupImg, posX1 + posX, posY, cupw, cuph);
context.drawImage(cupImg, posX2, posY, cupw, cuph);
context.drawImage(cupImg, posX3 - posX, posY, cupw, cuph);

i++;
if (i == density){
    steps ++;
    switch(ballPos){
        case 1:
            ballPos = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            ballPos = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            ballPos = 2;
            break;
    }
    clearInterval(timer);
    i = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to move the line `timer = setInterval(move_1_3, timeStep);` inside of the function `move_1_2`, positioned before the very end of that function.

If that doesn't work because of function reuse, you can still run one function after the other by using a single `setInterval` with an anonymous function:

```
    cupImg.onload = function(){
        timer = setInterval(function() {
                    move_1_2();
                    move_1_3();
                    // move_2_3();
                }, timeStep);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution which runs first the move_1_2 1000times, and THEN the move_1_3 1000 times, (don't run move_1_3 after every call of move_1_2)

Comment: See, that's the kind of fundamental information you should have put in the original question in the first place. Why don't you just use a loop to run the first 1000 times, without using `setInterval`?

Comment: It's kind of an animation. In 1000 times a picture appears in an other part of the window, if i only use a loop, only the endstate will be seen on the monitor.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's no longer clear to me what you're trying to achieve. You'd better update your original question with more details and a clear description of what you want the end result to be, compared to what you've accomplished so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in mechanic of setInterval function call

more information you can found here [settimeout-setinterval](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval)

> The minimal delay
>
> The timer resolution is limited. Actually, the minimal timer tick
>   varies between 1ms and 15ms for modern browsers and can be larger for
>   older ones.
>
> If the timer resolution is 10, then there is no difference between
>   setTimeout(..,1) and setTimeout(..,9).

you have 2 functions launched in the same time. you are not exactly know who will be first.
try to use something like this:

```
timer = setInterval(function(){move_1_2(); setInterval(move_1_3, timeStep);}, timeStep);
```

or try to use deferred.